# Symfony 4 Console Command not reading env vars

Tags: php, symfony, phpdotenv

I have a small console command where I'd like to read some environment variables, but it does not seem to read the vars from the `.env` file or the server configs in the console (php file works)

**The code**

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    $debug = $input->getArgument('debug') === 'y' ? true : false;
    $this->project = $input->getArgument('project');

    $start = new DateTime();

    $debug ? $io->text('<fg=green>Starting upload</>') : null;
    dump(getenv('APP_ENV'));
    dump(getenv('MAILER_USERNAME'));
    die;
    ...
}
```

**Commands to test**

`php bin/console app:make-backup`

Output:

```
Starting upload
false
false
```

`php bin/console app:make-backup --env=prod`

Output:

```
Starting upload
"prod"
false
```

`php bin/console app:make-backup --env=dev`

Output:

```
Starting upload
"dev"
false
```

**.env File**

```
APP_ENV=dev
MAILER_USERNAME=info@xxx.com
```

I don't see where I am doing wrong? Issue exists on nginx and apache server, BUT using `getenv('MAILER_USERNAME')` in any php-file works.

Comment: When you start your command directly in the shell, with `php bin/console what:ever`, that call to the PHP is not passing in automatically all the environment variables that you have active in the current shell. I had the same problem when trying to trigger the debugger with a `XDEBUG_SESSION=1` env var. In the end I had to do this `XDEBUG_SESSION=1 php bin/console what:ever` - only that will effectively set the wanted environment var for your command.

So, in your case `APP_ENV=dev php bin/console what:ever` should do it, like magic. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to go ahead and inject the env variables.  Trying to access them directly can be a bit tricky.

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Command\MyCommand:
        $appEnv:         '%env(APP_ENV)%'
        $mailerUsername: '%env(MAILER_USERNAME)%'

# src\Command\MyCommand
class MyCommand extends Command {
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:mine';

    private $appEnv;
    private $mailerUsername;

    public function __construct($appEnv,$mailerUsername) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->appEnv = $appEnv;
        $this->mailerUsername = $mailerUsername;
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $output->writeln(("My Command " . $this->appEnv . " " . $this->mailerUsername));
    }
}
```

Comment: It says `Cannot autowire service "App\Command\MyCommand": argument "$appEnv" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.` Removing the type-hinting throws a similar exception

Comment: See the first part of my answer.  You need an entry in config/services.yaml

Comment: I did and I changed it to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099308/1092632 but to no avail...

Comment: Take a break.  Then come back and review your code.  What I posted works.  You have a simple error someplace.

Comment: :) While I agree to that, this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902115/1092632 (the second part with the defaults). I may be a little too tired. Since I agree taht your code should work, I accept your answer anyway and say THANKS

Comment: In Symfony 5 i was able to retrieve the .env parameters directly in the commands with the global $_ENV['APP_ENV']